# Walking through a long flow during a short user test

Tags: user-research

I work at an company that sells an API, and we are trying to user test the process of signing up for an account and making your first API request. However, accounting for mistakes and missteps in the process, this can often take longer than a reasonable amount of time to speak with someone on the phone (30-45 minutes)

What are techniques to shorten the amount of time needed to conduct the test? It's difficult to skip parts of the flow on someones' computer as they generally build on each other.

Comment: OT: Like your avatar. Finger paint or paintball mishap?

Answer (score 2):

Kevin, I do not see why you are using a phone conversation for this. Why not invite some people to your office (or pay them a visit at home) and take the time for a decent task analysis.

If I would be asked to do a task analysis by phone, I would be mentally exhausted and frustrated after five minutes already.

I would suggest the following research setup:

- Gather 5 to 7 participants
- Give them a few dates to choose from
- Give them the option to be analysed at home or at your office (where being at home makes people more comfortable and includes all the contextual events)
- Prepare your task analysis
- Conduct the research
- Analyse results